# Failing prime factorisning program (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, debugging, prime-factoring

Im trying to solve [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) problem on programing.
Here is the question.

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Now I've cooked up a c++ program, which tries to check it by brute force, however, while executing its stuck at 5. Here is the Program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
const long long no = 600851475143;

long long isprime(long long p)
{
    long long reply = -1;
    long long i = 2;
    while (i < pow(p, 0.5)) {
        if (i % p == 0)
            reply = i;
    }
    if (reply == -1){
    return 0;
    cout<<" yup its prime "<<endl;  
    }

    else
        return reply;
}

long long factor(long long x)
{
     for (long long i = 2; i < no; i++) {
    cout<<"Trying "<<i<<endl;
        if ((isprime(i) == 0)&& (no % i == 0)) {
            return i;
        cout<<"found "<<i<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long ans = no;
    while (ans != 1) {
        cout << factor(ans) << endl;
        ans = ans / factor(ans);
    }
}
```

and this is the output

```
~/Desktop/proj$ ./a.out 

Trying 2
Trying 3
Trying 4
Trying 5
```

I really don't understand why its stuck at number 5, can someone help me out?

EDIT : Thanks b13rg , I realised my mistake . I now have a better algorithm , I have pasted it down for anybody needing it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

long long fun (long long x)
{
    for(long long i=2; i<sqrt(x);i++){
    while (x%i==0){
        cout<<i<<endl;
        x=x/i;
        }   
    }
}

int main(){

fun(600851475143);


return 0;}
```

Comment: Please learn to use debugger to solve these problems. Marking the question for closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to never change the value of i or p in the while loop in the function isprime.  It fails because sqrt(5) is larger than 2, and nothing in the while loop ever changes.

For the problem you're trying to solve:

You could first optimize the checking loop by only trying odd numbers, so first do 2, then 3, then 5 etc.  To make it even faster you could hard code in the first few primes, but that might be beyond the scope of this project.

To find the largest prime factor, you would want to first find the smallest prime factor.  For example, in the number above, the smallest is 5.  The next step would be to divide 13195 by 5 to get 2369.  Then start again to find the smallest prime factor of this number, and keep going until the dividing result is prime.

```
Number|Smallest prime
------|--------------
13169 | 5
2369  | 7
377   |13
29    |Largest prime factor of 13169
```